# MeshTools' CylinderMesh fails in MMA version 12.3.1

Tags: mesh

I cannot run the `CylinderMesh` function of [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) in *Mathematica* version 12.3.1.

```
$Version
(*Install MeshTools*)
ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["c3m-labs", "MeshTools"];
(*Load MeshTools package*)
Needs["MeshTools`"]
mesh = CylinderMesh[{6, 4}]
(* "12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
(* $Failed *)
```

[image: Error]

Can anybody reproduce the error or suggest what might be wrong with the code?

## Update

After some investigation, I discovered that the problematic function call is in [`FindGeometricTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeometricTransform.html). The following shows the automatic determination of the transformation class for `FindGeometricTransform` fails for a simple 3D translation.

```
FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 2}}]
(* FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 2}}] *)
```

[image: Find geometric transform error]

One can remedy the problem by explicitly defining transformation class like so:

```
FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   2}}, TransformationClass -> "Translation"]
```

[image: Successful find geometric transformation]

@user21 filed this as a bug report as indicated in his comment to his answer. I also submitted a support request [CASE:4846569].

Comment: Also failed on Linux 12.3.1

Comment: Seems have been fixed. Work in 13.3.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what is going on in the package, but here is a workaround:

```
mesh = DiskMesh[5];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
ExtrudeMesh[mesh, 1, 5]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is a short/sweet workaround.  I did a little digging and found that `FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   2}}]` fails.  One has to explicitly set the transformation class like so `FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   2}}, TransformationClass -> "Translation"]`. I would expect the Automatic methods should be able to do a better job on the TransformationClass.  Do you agree?

Comment: @TimLaska Yes, this is a bug, I believe, and I filed it as such. It worked in 12.2.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I submitted a support case last night too, but I suspect yours may carry more weight ;).